# Why my warsaw color in headline is not correct?

Tags: beamer

I use the warsaw theme and use some outtheme. But I found that my theme color in the headline is not from blue to dark. It likes from light-blue to dark-blue.

The picture of my slides is as fololows:
[image]

But I want my slides' headline use the follow color:
[image]

You can see the difference of them.

My code is shared on the overleaf, so what can I do to change the color?, Thanks.

The code address: [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/9731719369kgkjdyzgsqsy)

The partial code is in the following:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, compress, % Set the default font size, options include: 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt
    %t, % Uncomment to vertically align all slide content to the top of the slide, rather than the default centered
    aspectratio=169, % Uncomment to set the aspect ratio to a 16:9 ratio which matches the aspect ratio of 1080p and 4K screens and projectors
]{beamer}


\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{default} % Typeset using the default sans serif font
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font for serif text
\usepackage[default]{opensans} % Use the Open Sans font for sans serif text
\useinnertheme{circles}

\useoutertheme{infolines} % to show the information below the body
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes} % to show the navigation above the frame title
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@headline{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt%
}{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip5pt% modify 5pt to change the distance avoiding the cut of the navigation circle
}{}{}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[tick]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[tick]

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Uncomment this line to remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides
```

Comment: Please don't expect people to click an external link, instead make your question self-contained. Read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and provide some short compilable code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this question by add the following code:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
```

and also cannot use the following outertheme:

```
%\useoutertheme{infolines} % to show the information below the body
```

Then, the result is as follows:
[image]